# Why in _Layout.cshtml section with environment exclude="Development" is not excluded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET MVC solution in .NET 5 with a simple _Layout.chhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    
    @RenderBody()

    <environment include="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

I expect that in Development mode (running from VS 2019) minimized versions of JavaScript and CSS are **NOT** loaded.

However every time I start the application from Visual Studio all variants both not minimized and minimized (both JavaScript and CSS) are loaded into pages. Why?

Do I misunderstand the concept of `<environment exclude="Development">` tag?

Comment: the code looks fine, it should not render the links for minified resources. I doubt that there is a wrong assumption here. You should prepare a blank page/view using that layout to see if the issue still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<environment exclude="Development">` is a so called Razor tag helper.

In order to activate Razor tag helpers a special directive needs to be used on a Razor page:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Tag helpers do not work without this.

Or better to add a list of **@** directives in a separate file named `_ViewImports.cshtml`

For example:

```
@using MyApp
@namespace MyApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```